# Fragments deprecated in Android P

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-9.0-pie

I was looking at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and found this

> This class was deprecated in API level P.

Why are fragments deprecated in android P?

Comment: Those who've downvoted/considering downvote, can you please also give a valid reason? I think it's a genuine question and can provide us all with some insightful answers.

Comment: Questions for reasons of doing something make only sense if you ask the one who does it. In this case you have to ask Google.

Comment: Does still make sense to use Fragments in 2018, now that only the support implementation is operating? What to use instead?

Comment: @RoyalGriffin, downvoters are haters. They cannot explain their behaviour, they just see rules of SO (which are illogical), then mark with minuses and ask moderators to close or remove a question (and sometimes a right answer).

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, at least, some libraries use fragments without support.v4. In new projects we also used them. Even AS adds fragments by default (with File > New > Fragment).

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Google representatives are reading and interacting with Android related questions on SO, so it is the right forum.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Any proof tht they interact with such kind of questions? I have never seen it...

Comment: @TheincredibleJan see Doug on https://stackoverflow.com/q/36487971/253468; that being said there's no guarantee they'll give valuable info :(

Comment: @RoyalGriffin I didn't know about this question and I asked it here and was down voted and closed too! looks like a political question that should't be asked!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274560/fragments-are-depreciated-what-is-the-alternative

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## The rewrite in Support Library 27.1.0

[Ian's medium post](https://medium.com/google-developers/loaders-in-support-library-27-1-0-b1a1f0fee638) (Feb 28, 2018) gives us an explanation about it. He is Android Framework Developer at Google.

> **Loaders in Support Library 27.1.0**
>
> For Support Library 27.1.0, I rewrote the internals of LoaderManager, the class powering the Loaders API and I wanted to explain the reasoning behind the changes and what to expect going forward.
>
> **Loaders and Fragments, a history**
>   From the beginning, Loaders and Fragments were pretty tightly tied together at the hip. This meant that a lot of the code in FragmentActivity and Fragment were there to support Loaders, despite the fact that there are indeed fairly independent. …
>
> **What’s changed in 27.1.0**
>   With 27.1.0, the technical debt of Loaders has been greatly reduced: …
>
> …
>
> Note: Obviously, these changes only apply to Support Library Loaders. If you are using Android framework Loaders, please switch to the Support Library Loaders as soon as possible. There are no bug fixes or improvements planned for the framework Loader APIs.

It seems like the code in `Fragment` and `FragmentActivity` has been refactored in order to make Loaders an optional dependency.

According to [the release note](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-1-0), the new implementation is based on `Lifecycle`.

> **Important Changes**
>   The underlying implementation of [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) has been rewritten to use [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html).

## Architecture Components

In [Support Library 26.1.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#26-1-0), `Fragment` and `FragmentActivity` has adopted `Lifecycle`.

> This is a special release to integrate the Support Library with Lifecycles from Architecture Components. If you are not using the Lifecycles library, you don’t need to update from 26.0.2. For more information, see the Architecture Components release notes.
>
> **Important changes**
>
> - Fragment and FragmentActivity (the base class for AppCompatActivity) now implement the LifecycleOwner interface from Architecture Components.

By contrast, [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in Android P have not implemented the interface `LifecycleOwner`.

In [the Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/WAGQiG7LaKs) (mentioned in [ThanosFisherman’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49446585/9298629)), Ian made a comment:

> you can't change framework code after it has shipped - it is literally frozen in time. That means no new features and more importantly no bug fixes. That's not a good developer experience, particularly when we do have a fully supported, up to date, backward compatible version in the Support Library.

I think that’s the reason why Android P doesn't adopt `Lifecycle`. Consequently `Fragment` is deprecated in Android P.

Answer (score 14):

In case anyone was looking for the way to instantiate fragments by the class name.

#### Old way:

`Fragment.instantiate(context, fragmentClass)`

#### New way:

```
val fm: FragmentManager = ...
fm.fragmentFactory.instantiate(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), fragmentClass)
```

---

#### Using an extension:

File name:  `FragmentManagerExt.kt`

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager

fun FragmentManager.instantiate(className: String): Fragment {
    return fragmentFactory.instantiate(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), className)
}
```

#### Example usage:

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.instantiate(fragmentClassName)
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your supportFragmentManager solution..

Answer (score 11):

Support Library Fragments are here to stay. Google encourages you to use the Support Library versions to get consistent behavior across all API levels, backported bug fixes, and Lifecycle and ViewModel support.

[Old Reference Link(Dead)](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/WAGQiG7LaKs)

[New Reference Link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/loaders-in-support-library-27-1-0-b1a1f0fee638)

Comment: Google+ is closed, so where you can find the information about this ?

Comment: @OscarLeif See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/loaders-in-support-library-27-1-0-b1a1f0fee638

Answer (score 1):

Use **supportFragmentManager**   in stead of  **fragmentManager** in **Android x**.