# Fragments and DialogFragments deprecated, what will replace them?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

We can read in official Android doc

> android.app.Fragment
>   This class was deprecated in API level 28.
>   Use
>   the Support Library Fragment for consistent behavior across all
>   devices and access to Lifecycle.This class was deprecated in API level 28.

What is going on ?
What we should use now instead of Fragments and DialogFragments ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragments deprecated in Android P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446411/fragments-deprecated-in-android-p)

Comment: android.app.Fragment and android.app.DialogFragment is deprecated in API 28, use android.support.v4.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the import statement only.

From : android.app.Fragment
To: android.support.v4.app.Fragment

That's it

Comment: or `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;` in android X

Answer (score 0):

Now,You can use Fragment Support library (AndroidX) from Android P(28).

Add following in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Add following dependency in project `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
```

Change import statement from

**Fragment:** `import android.app.Fragment;`

**DialogFragment:** `import android.app.DialogFragment;`

TO

**Fragment:** `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;`

**DialogFragment:** `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;`

Reference link provided by Google: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate